# How to program without "unsafeWindow"?

Tags: javascript, security, greasemonkey

In my Greasemonkey script, I would like to override a function that still exists in the webpage.

So I'm using this JavaScript code:

```
var oldDoWork = DoWork;

unsafeWindow.DoWork = function()
{
    // Do some new work
    ...

    oldDoWork(); // Call the old function
}
```

It works.

But there are two problems with that method:

1. The `unsafeWindow` feature is a security problem, from Greasemonkey says.
2. In this new function, we can't use `GM_getValue` and `GM_setValue`. The workaround of using a timer causes some other problems of asynchronous job.

How do I manage the above code without using `unsafeWindow`?

Comment: `The workaround of using a timer causes some other problems of asynchronous job.`

What problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid unsafeWindow, you could use:

```
location.assign("javascript:YOUR_CODE_GOES_HERE");
```

But this won't let you use GM_* functions either.

And the only way to use GM_* "out of the GM scope" is using a timer.

So basically, the answer to your question is: you are in the correct way, you just can't do much about it.

If your function doesn't return anything then I would recommend you to use `location.assign`

Comment: It seems to be you are right : it's impossible to use GM_getValue inside unsafewindow. The only workaround is to use setTimeout with 0 ms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `unsafeWindow`, inject the code -- that interacts with the page's JS -- into the page.  See `addJS_Node()`, below.

To trigger GM_ functions from within such events, you *should* be able to interact via:

- Writing nodes and listening to `DOMSubtreeModified` (deprecated in W3C spec).  BUT, [a bug in FF/GM prevents this for now](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1210).
- Sending custom events.  Again, [GM/FF bugs and features prevent that for now](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/greasemonkey-dev/j3bq2WjCTrU/MVd5Gxl4WN4J).
  Note that a `click` event, for example, can call code that uses GM_ functions ***when the user physically clicks***.  BUT, generate the same click event programmatically, and it fails with the `"Greasemonkey access violation: unsafeWindow cannot call..."` error.

So, for the moment, the workaround is still to use a timer, **but** you can avoid `unsafeWindow`, if you wish:

```
//--- Put everything that goes into the main page, inside myJS().
function myJS () {

    window.oldDoWork = DoWork;

    window.DoWork = function() {
        // Do some new work

        callGM_setValue ("From target page", "some value");

        window.oldDoWork(); // Call the old function
    }

    function callGM_setValue (varName, varValue) {

        //--- Generate and dispatch a synthetic event.
        var zEvent  = document.createEvent ("CustomEvent");
        zEvent.initCustomEvent (
            "messageToGM_setvalue", true, false,
            {Name: varName, Value: varValue}
        );

        document.body.dispatchEvent (zEvent);
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener (
    "messageToGM_setvalue", fireGM_setValue, false
);

function fireGM_setValue (zEvent) {

    /*--- setTimeout remains one of the few things that can cleanse
        the calling tree of it's "unsafe" origins.
    */
    setTimeout (function() {
        GM_setValue (zEvent.detail.Name, zEvent.detail.Value);
    }, 0);
}

addJS_Node (null, null, myJS);

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D           = document;
    var scriptNode  = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' 
                                            +   funcToRun.toString()
                                            + ')()';

     var targ    = D.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
                || D.body
                || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```